# csv to php read entire directory

Tags: php, csv

Is there a way to make use of this script? but instead of 1 file it reads an entire directory? and then shows it on a webpage? at the moment it only shows 1 csv file. I dont know if I can use glob for this. my php knowledge is improving but I still terrible at this. XD

```
<?PHP  

$file_handle = fopen("../test.csv", "r");  

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {  

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);  

                echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td></tr>'; 

                }  

fclose($file_handle);  

?>
```

Comment: A whole directory holds CSV files and you want to render the content of all CSV files in 1 directory on a webpage in some sort of table?

Comment: yes exactly that. and also want them divided, this is prob impossible though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) to fetch a list of files in your directory, then loop through them with `foreach()` and use your existing code.

```
<?php

$arrFiles = glob("../*.csv");
foreach($arrFiles as $strFileName) {
   $file_handle = fopen($strFileName, "r");  
   while (!feof($file_handle) ) {  
      $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);  
      echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td></tr>'; 
   }  
   fclose($file_handle);  
}
```

You *might* want to limit the amount of files you open and close rather than opening **all** files in that directory - or cache the results.

To limit the amount of files you open, you can use `array_slice`;

```
$arrFiles = glob("../*.csv");
$arrFiles = array_slice($arrFiles, 0, 10); //Limit to 10 files
```

#### Sorting output based on date modified

What you need to do is grab a list of files, then get their last modified time, then sort that array. For example:

```
$arrFiles = glob("../*.csv");
$arrSortedFiles = array();
foreach($arrFiles as $strFileName) {
   $arrSortedFiles[$strFileName] = filemtime($strFileName);
}
natsort($arrSortedFiles); //Sort naturally. Oldest first. 
foreach(array_keys($arrSortedFiles) as $strFileName) {
     //...
}
```

If, however, you want the sort the other way around - newest first - then just use `array_reverse()`.

Comment: you should use `$strFileName` instead of `../test.csv`

Comment: It works, and ur right I should limit on it. is it possible with an array slice?

Comment: Thank @RaphaelMüller - an oversight when c&p code. Yes `array_slice` will do that for you :)

Comment: Is there also a way to sort the csv based on last day modified?

Comment: Can I still set like 5 files to show even with newest first?

Comment: Yes. `array_slice()` after `natsort()`.